# Nested for loops displays only last iteration

Tags: r, loops, nested

I have created a function that filters a dataframe based on some unique values of 2 different columns. I'm trying to loop thru the unique values of cell type(3) as well as unique values from another column called Cell_line(2). I've created two lists to hold this information and am using a nested loop to count thru each. The New Dataframe seems to be the last iteration of each list (cell_line and types) and omits the other outputs. How can I obtain these as well. either a list of dataframes or a single dataframe with all the information bound together would work

```
### My function takes a few arguments and gives a new dataframe
myfunction <- function(data_frame,type,Cell) {
    prism <- df2%>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    filter(.,TYPE == type & Cell_Line == Cell) %>%
    pivot_wider(., id_cols = c("Treatment_rep","value","lipid"),
        names_from = Treatment_rep, values_from = value)
    prism$Cell_line <- Cell
    prism  
}



### I'm attempting to feed these into my function iteratively
cell_lines <- unique(df2$Cell_Line)              ## list of 3 types
types <- unique(df2$TYPE)                        ### list of 2 types




### nested loop
for (i in 1:length(types)) {
    for(j in 1: length(cell_lines)) {
        newdf <- myfunction(data_frame = df2, type = types[i], Cell = cell_lines[j])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
dflist <- list()

for (i in 1:length(types)){
  for(j in 1: length(cell_lines)){
    newdf <- myfunction(data_frame = df2, type = types[i], Cell = cell_lines[j])
    dflist[[ length(dflist)+1 ]] <- newdf
  }
}
```

And if afterwards you want to bind them all together

```
df_total <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

Comment: I will try this....I eventually solved the issue by making an empty list of df frames before hand...this is much cleaner                                                                                       empty3<-letters[1:(length(cell_lines)*length(types))]#number of dataframes

matrix_dim<-prism_normalized_function(data_frame = df4, type = types[1], Cell = cell_lines[1])      #we have the diminsions we need
dim(matrix_dim)

empty3<-lapply(empty3, function(x){
  x=matrix(1:dim(matrix_dim)[1]*dim(matrix_dim)[2], dim(matrix_dim)[1],dim(matrix_dim)[2])
})

Comment: I eventually solved the issue by making an empty list of df frames outside my function before hand...yours  is much cleaner....  the tricky part was matching the dimensions of my empty list to the data going in but once that was solved everything worked.